# Drawing lines within circle using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I'm trying to draw some lines within a circle of arbitrary size. I want to start with one vertical line through the centre of the circle and then add further lines like so:

[image]

I want to be able to control the spacing between the lines, L, and the number of lines plotted out from the centre (in the example there are two on either side of the centre line). The red markings are just for a guide I don't need that in the final version.

What is the best way to code this using TikZ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm); % The choice of 1cm was arbitrary, what is the best way to scale this diagram?
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw (3,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (3,-1) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The best way is to calculate the endpoints using pgfmath: `y=sqrt{r*r-x*x)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using clipping? I am using a `scope` here to restrict the clipping to it.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope} 
        \draw  [clip] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1); % first (center) line 
            \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {% 4 lines per side 
                \draw (\x/10, -1) -- (\x/10,1); % positive x position 0.1, 0.2...
                \draw (-\x/10, -1) -- (-\x/10,1); % and negative ones 
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Notice that the seemingly bigger line at the center is an aliasing problem of the PDF viewer).

Using scopes let you manipulate the thing quite easily:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \draw  [clip] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1); % first diagonal
            \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {% 4 lines 
                \draw (\x/10, -1) -- (\x/10,1);
                \draw (-\x/10, -1) -- (-\x/10,1);
        }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, scale=0.5, rotate=45]
        \draw  [clip] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1); % first diagonal
            \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {% 4 lines 
                \draw (\x/10, -1) -- (\x/10,1);
                \draw (-\x/10, -1) -- (-\x/10,1);
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

For fun, here is a style `vlines` using `path picture` and `grid` to draw the lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  vlines/.style={
    path picture={
      \draw[xstep=#1, ystep=100cm, shift={(path picture bounding box.south west)} ]
      (path picture bounding box.south west) grid (path picture bounding box.north east);
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[vlines=2mm] (0,0) circle (1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note :** The `ystep=100cm` can be set to the height of `path picture bounding box` but this is another story ;)

Answer (score 1):

With the neweast version of TikZ/PGF, the best way should be `grid[ystep=0,xstep=\L]` after `clip` inside the unit circle. Note that the grid always go through the center. You have full control via `\L` for horizontal spacing between lines (hence, number of lines) and `[scale=2]` for scalethe whole picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] 
\def\L{1.5mm}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle(1);
\draw (-1,-1) grid[ystep=0,xstep=\L] (1,1);
\draw[red] (0,-1)--(0,1); % for checking grid go through the center, should be removed
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```